# How to have QA and Production installed via ClickOnce without overriding each other?

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, clickonce, manifest

I am having a problem attempting to have two environments published through [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce).

I have two URLs, one with the QA version and one with the PROD version. The issue is that I can only have one at the time. If I install one, it overrides the other instance.

I already attempted to change the publisher name and also add a Suite name to create a subfolder, but they still mutual exclude each other.

Comment: Would the answer given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754318/how-do-i-deploy-two-clickonce-versions-simultaneously) be of any use to you?