# Changing ClickOnce to use new install url with other PublicKeyToken

Tags: .net, wpf, clickonce

We have multible install url to different servers around the world, we solved this by doing like this.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1754418/1412478

But now we now have 14 projects where we need to maintain the app.config and other stuff.
We would like to do it like this instead, so that we only have one project.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6203614/1412478

Now the problem is that we have a lot of customers around the world that have installed the application and would like them not to have to reinstall the application.
I have tried to change the PublicKeyToken and what .application file project points to so that it should think that it is the same application. But I get this error

> Following failure messages were detected:         + Exception reading
>   manifest from
>   https://qainstall.opnbibliotheca.com/install/LibraryAdministrationAzureNordicQA.application:
>   the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.        +
>   Manifest XML signature is not valid.      + Generic trust failure.

Is there anybody that have an idea what needs to be changed in the manifest file etc. to do this?

---

I solved that issue. I now get an error saying:
The deployment identity does not match the subscription.

I checked that the CPU architecture is the same.
Here is the original file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1 assembly.adaptive.xsd" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xrml="urn:mpeg:mpeg21:2003:01-REL-R-NS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:co.v1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1" xmlns:co.v2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2">
  <assemblyIdentity name="LibraryAdministrationAzureNordicQA.application" version="1.5.2.75" publicKeyToken="3dfe2efc282aafa8" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="x86" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
  <description asmv2:publisher="bibliotheca" asmv2:product="open+ administration QA" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
  <deployment install="true" mapFileExtensions="true" minimumRequiredVersion="1.5.2.68" co.v1:createDesktopShortcut="true">
    <subscription>
      <update>
        <beforeApplicationStartup />
      </update>
    </subscription>
    <deploymentProvider codebase="https://qainstall.opnbibliotheca.com/install/LibraryAdministrationAzureNordicQA.application" />
  </deployment>
  <compatibleFrameworks xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2">
    <framework targetVersion="4.6.2" profile="Full" supportedRuntime="4.0.30319" />
  </compatibleFrameworks>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" codebase="Application Files\LibraryAdministrationAzureNordicQA_1_5_2_75\LibraryAdministrationAzureNordicQA.exe.manifest" size="106774">
      <assemblyIdentity name="LibraryAdministrationAzureNordicQA.exe" version="1.5.2.75" publicKeyToken="3dfe2efc282aafa8" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="x86" type="win32" />
      <hash>
        <dsig:Transforms>
          <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
        </dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha256" />
        <dsig:DigestValue>iw0CDphUvFC564L3vv+3y9lQ0RIOQDNzTBOVrGiiCoE=</dsig:DigestValue>
      </hash>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
<publisherIdentity name="CN=&quot;BIBLIOTHECA, LLC&quot;, O=&quot;BIBLIOTHECA, LLC&quot;, L=NORCROSS, S=Georgia, C=US" issuerKeyHash="40c2bd278ecc348330a233d7fb6cb3f0b42c80ce" /><Signature Id="StrongNameSignature" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha256" /><Reference URI=""><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha256" /><DigestValue>TpLwYoZFOXzkYb2rT5yUlCLJ1nkCY3sJ5lozpaIY27k=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>InYpUJ0JiErFXLYfocrTA6lr6SsoCGB+L7KSdd8LHeXCTRlTAqK3XAyV+LU6PP2Hvzv8pkzpI8YZMeq0a2KY+rmyCZbNLou6ANKi5lCpPAMoneo87JibiNCvAROxOBOwdqQKfBJNNRgg0x3y4Hqm+LUgO53/CjcjEf38Z4R57t4fWL63ZpxZuLJDNTfv6m1KhWLOWCZ61XPN1kpJXId5dh6nagqP3EnPD2qJjVnWd3wrNDnIUaqu89QHkFKiLWBVnc/fInJjubmOzhGSR3x/3UDNV1fdne1accY8x80+evwSuH0X6TF11D8Tl5VP9P9kpZoITdftaULmea4harGBlg==</SignatureValue><KeyInfo Id="StrongNameKeyInfo"><KeyValue><RSAKeyValue><Modulus>y0lssN0rdjZ45cKvfdMydKifyQE5Y5jmlfwgUB2t78kCGBkTKMPfFTNAmzoG9Lz5TgbvOX9iM7iq7cRxwG2RL93L1bkjtj57LOs+Xv6poKChuQJnrtaJF5OlORVh64QnPkEQbotL0DG+Z12LNBxA1DqkX2RxXLfSn77gk2FSKqc/b0iCVGRu0toPUrh0IpCODJR3xNvmDKUSl/Op/1rJYdf4/gt9BTyJuegjvqZqbAfaUBtMpbXQH4rWZ5rdWTGW4NDh7sCnd/94EHC2cbDikKk5vwIxiBsq9sFblVC0kVhsY3WTbQY0N8XINtFp4R+VdVt4oyRMGP27qrEEHGAYJQ==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue></KeyValue><msrel:RelData xmlns:msrel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/rel/2005/reldata"><r:license xmlns:r="urn:mpeg:mpeg21:2003:01-REL-R-NS" xmlns:as="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/pki/2005/Authenticode"><r:grant><as:ManifestInformation Hash="b9db18a2a5335ae6097b630279d6c92294949c4fabbd61e47c39458662f0924e" Description="" Url=""><as:assemblyIdentity name="LibraryAdministrationAzureNordicQA.application" version="1.5.2.75" publicKeyToken="3dfe2efc282aafa8" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="x86" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" /></as:ManifestInformation><as:SignedBy /><as:AuthenticodePublisher><as:X509SubjectName>CN="BIBLIOTHECA, LLC", O="BIBLIOTHECA, LLC", L=NORCROSS, S=Georgia, C=US</as:X509SubjectName></as:AuthenticodePublisher></r:grant><r:issuer><Signature Id="AuthenticodeSignature" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha256" /><Reference URI=""><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha256" /><DigestValue>cDe/loY5uL+jKrqJvmLC9CxCSjsppRlILSVwaksDi/8=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>pCFABD8N/9UlgdNpa0gQ/kLBqud7jxkFq5G3VA/8BxjcmVTgk3YMAvv50E6V1TupiOzcrqblFXq93yCA/76//THKTe+2oh/K9+p9DONKPKn6ZKQr/g76952SvcQLzZIDmUyHiljL2eYUkikaP8baqwHh100ZyIpIrRGt2gHvO90V0Cz/OnDDIlt+qkTfRqbzOIBSS562HMiUvrezcEV5oO26aJ/rZj8QjZRZRIcITSA5YEY1K96zIBFuSyr+hkNtK2mPFDiYaw7G84IWOnnI4X+fr9hJJtzgNkMxQ0RqSDXvVwcUhVYkPBJR/aMuqxLUxJPaWaqsXXZ6oJgQgnd0Xg==</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><KeyValue><RSAKeyValue><Modulus>y0lssN0rdjZ45cKvfdMydKifyQE5Y5jmlfwgUB2t78kCGBkTKMPfFTNAmzoG9Lz5TgbvOX9iM7iq7cRxwG2RL93L1bkjtj57LOs+Xv6poKChuQJnrtaJF5OlORVh64QnPkEQbotL0DG+Z12LNBxA1DqkX2RxXLfSn77gk2FSKqc/b0iCVGRu0toPUrh0IpCODJR3xNvmDKUSl/Op/1rJYdf4/gt9BTyJuegjvqZqbAfaUBtMpbXQH4rWZ5rdWTGW4NDh7sCnd/94EHC2cbDikKk5vwIxiBsq9sFblVC0kVhsY3WTbQY0N8XINtFp4R+VdVt4oyRMGP27qrEEHGAYJQ==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue></KeyValue><X509Data><X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate><X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate></X509Data></KeyInfo><Object><as:Timestamp>MIIRywYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIRvDCCEbgCAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMIIBEwYJKoZI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=
</as:Timestamp></Object></Signature></r:issuer></r:license></msrel:RelData></KeyInfo></Signature></asmv1:assembly>
```

And here is the file i created myself.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1 assembly.adaptive.xsd" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:co.v1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xrml="urn:mpeg:mpeg21:2003:01-REL-R-NS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity name="LibraryAdministrationAzureNordicQA.application" version="1.6.0.5" publicKeyToken="3dfe2efc282aafa8" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="x86" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
  <description asmv2:publisher="open+ administration QA" asmv2:product="open+ administration QA" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
  <deployment install="true" mapFileExtensions="true" minimumRequiredVersion="1.6.0.1" co.v1:createDesktopShortcut="true">
    <subscription>
      <update>
        <beforeApplicationStartup />
      </update>
    </subscription>
    <deploymentProvider codebase="https://qainstall.opnbibliotheca.com/install/LibraryAdministrationAzureNordicQA.application" />
  </deployment>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" codebase="Application Files\LibraryAdministrationAzureNordicQA_1_6_0_5\LibraryAdministrationAzureNordicQA.exe.manifest" size="58414">
      <assemblyIdentity name="LibraryAdministrationAzureNordicQA.exe" version="1.6.0.5" publicKeyToken="3dfe2efc282aafa8" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="x86" type="win32" />
      <hash>
        <dsig:Transforms>
          <dsig:Transform Algorithm="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:HashTransforms.Identity" />
        </dsig:Transforms>
        <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <dsig:DigestValue>bj4Rmff3KARAn1cIOQpbtyhebpqCD5ykKx8wPg6+x+Q=</dsig:DigestValue>
      </hash>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <compatibleFrameworks xmlns:co.v2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2">
    <framework targetVersion="4.6.2" profile="Full" supportedRuntime="4.0.30319" />
  </compatibleFrameworks>
  <publisherIdentity name="CN=&quot;BIBLIOTHECA, LLC&quot;, O=&quot;BIBLIOTHECA, LLC&quot;, L=NORCROSS, S=Georgia, C=US" issuerKeyHash="40c2bd278ecc348330a233d7fb6cb3f0b42c80ce" xmlns:co.v2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v2" />
<Signature Id="StrongNameSignature" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" /><Reference URI=""><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" /><DigestValue>bRPuXocuB0b1OaCmKRsXUtptgDQ=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>L7Une4Uv9Rr/5iLo9j/bEnaPK5+sJCavloqbr5NKKGtZxfgx7X+GkrjKYdsLAQ/KYYhsDbc6PC2i6gadiFkDiZz6Kxi5Ji9T2zIG339TC5XC97hcC/gKizuTB3zerBRwrrAMFb9+5d3hNCIQdTF9Uzh6gjC8LgJnjqWfeBnbhTM1PYCZsJ0RMonjf955K36toPuQ4w3UZIuhHD4CbYnpIMIVerUpCzGrP4kR2FcRj/0IwIAFoz/lTk/I87Mlpwov59wH2znClU12g2aKUqRd4Fl1vdz5HmBlL7okgtPlQH/ouFr9nYVsMNFZCiWhv2qEFHNHdgQxCE/teqZEyFNpow==</SignatureValue><KeyInfo Id="StrongNameKeyInfo"><KeyValue><RSAKeyValue><Modulus>y0lssN0rdjZ45cKvfdMydKifyQE5Y5jmlfwgUB2t78kCGBkTKMPfFTNAmzoG9Lz5TgbvOX9iM7iq7cRxwG2RL93L1bkjtj57LOs+Xv6poKChuQJnrtaJF5OlORVh64QnPkEQbotL0DG+Z12LNBxA1DqkX2RxXLfSn77gk2FSKqc/b0iCVGRu0toPUrh0IpCODJR3xNvmDKUSl/Op/1rJYdf4/gt9BTyJuegjvqZqbAfaUBtMpbXQH4rWZ5rdWTGW4NDh7sCnd/94EHC2cbDikKk5vwIxiBsq9sFblVC0kVhsY3WTbQY0N8XINtFp4R+VdVt4oyRMGP27qrEEHGAYJQ==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue></KeyValue><msrel:RelData xmlns:msrel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/rel/2005/reldata"><r:license xmlns:r="urn:mpeg:mpeg21:2003:01-REL-R-NS" xmlns:as="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/pki/2005/Authenticode"><r:grant><as:ManifestInformation Hash="34806dda52171b29a6a039f546072e875eee136d" Description="" Url=""><as:assemblyIdentity name="LibraryAdministrationAzureNordicQA.application" version="1.6.0.5" publicKeyToken="3dfe2efc282aafa8" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="x86" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" /></as:ManifestInformation><as:SignedBy /><as:AuthenticodePublisher><as:X509SubjectName>CN="BIBLIOTHECA, LLC", O="BIBLIOTHECA, LLC", L=NORCROSS, S=Georgia, C=US</as:X509SubjectName></as:AuthenticodePublisher></r:grant><r:issuer><Signature Id="AuthenticodeSignature" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" /><Reference URI=""><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" /><DigestValue>yRsSnBwEFEC13GjxJQJe7MSyF+g=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>h2yKs91rNwZ3bki5gYPd5oUesBafIPSaCRg9oqS/soybLmrr2gkCgfPRyDKVhFU8sGRHstuNjlMAuTJRJ+2R3VfLUmHqAUocxkDRt1wc77DVHXSzA9E8Ig2TXKdMySGriBAdpVSI+jZNL/dTbbI0PIJLeNLGYQy5mOeTUUVcf6cCy8vXjZcy1b2vek6rEw14Up5iTglI83FQDdfcCSPGGqY2NVfyNEe/nQIxl6gfrF4hLzs/iJGjdB5U+S6m6eobp5cEft8xVNSBRm5kD/AKs3Mmb5XyQAStBkShdtFVXifBaDL9WApr4fhkJahd6ixjwGPs80NYDPcjcmHElrySsA==</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><KeyValue><RSAKeyValue><Modulus>y0lssN0rdjZ45cKvfdMydKifyQE5Y5jmlfwgUB2t78kCGBkTKMPfFTNAmzoG9Lz5TgbvOX9iM7iq7cRxwG2RL93L1bkjtj57LOs+Xv6poKChuQJnrtaJF5OlORVh64QnPkEQbotL0DG+Z12LNBxA1DqkX2RxXLfSn77gk2FSKqc/b0iCVGRu0toPUrh0IpCODJR3xNvmDKUSl/Op/1rJYdf4/gt9BTyJuegjvqZqbAfaUBtMpbXQH4rWZ5rdWTGW4NDh7sCnd/94EHC2cbDikKk5vwIxiBsq9sFblVC0kVhsY3WTbQY0N8XINtFp4R+VdVt4oyRMGP27qrEEHGAYJQ==</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue></KeyValue><X509Data><X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate><X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate></X509Data></KeyInfo></Signature></r:issuer></r:license></msrel:RelData></KeyInfo></Signature></asmv1:assembly>
```

The only thing I can think of is different is the signature, but I am using the exact same certificate. The only difference is that original version is signed by Visual Studio and the one I created myself is signed by mage.

Thanks
Anders

Comment: It is necessary to sign the manifest file manually with mage.exe after changing any file contents. Have you tried this?

Comment: It worked. Now I get this error: Cannot make this application an online application because the previous version is installed. To install this application uninstall the previous version, or mark this application as installed. But my project is set to an offline application.