# Having Different groups install separate ClickOnce Versions

Tags: .net, visual-studio, deployment, clickonce, msdeploy

What We are trying to accomplish:

1. We are looking into having some beta groups that will have the newest version of our ClickOnce application.
2. We also need to be able to control who is in these groups from backend.
3. All groups should install from same directory, just different versions.

Is there a way to install A previous version of clickonce without deleting the .application link like shown here: http://geekswithblogs.net/gpro/archive/2008/10/30/clickonce-restore-previous-version.aspx

The long version,

We want to control (prgrammatically) through database and AD user's [Ring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/phase-rollout-with-rings?view=azure-devops) access  to the application. They should all have the same installation to the application, so that we do not need to uninstall the application if we change their ring.

Initial install should be their correct ring version if possible. 
Afterwards, **onLoad** of application, we run a check to determine, user's ring and required version (we have this working).

Next step is to install the correct version - which is where we need some help.

[image]

In the image, if you are Ring 1, you should have latest version installed 1.0.0.23.
if you are Ring 2, you should have previous version 1.0.0.22.

The question is, how to install a previous version programmatically.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1754418/1109794

Comment: it doesnt, because i cannot move people between rings without installing new application