# How to use ConfigurationManager for DEBUG and RELEASE versions in VS 2008 projects

Tags: .net, configuration, web-config, app-config

i would like to use the "ConfigurationManager" settings, that i can create in VS 2008 ( see image ), to create different behaviors in my web.config or app.config files... for example i want to use different connection strings, if the "debug"-configuration is active, like:

```
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings configSource="connectionStrings.config.$(ConfigurationName)"/>
</configuration>
```

[image]

Any suggestions how to do that? ( Or maybe in another way than this? )

Thanks

Comment: Refer to this. . .

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132544/net-configuration-app-config-web-config-settings-settings

Answer (score 0):

How about web.config transformation? [How to: Transform Web.config When Deploying a Web Application Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx).

Comment: I believe this is only .NET Framework 4, so you can't use that with VS2008.