# Howto backup / restore user Settings to / from another file in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have written a program that stores its settings to a .user file using the standard ConfigurationManager mechanism.
Now I would like to implement a method "save as" and "load" where the user can store his program settings to another location. Is there another possibility other than to copy the physical file?

Comment: http://snipplr.com/view/24482/ "Persisting data using XML config files in WinForms (saving and restoring user and application data)" Also at SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869628/how-to-use-net-configuration-files-app-config-settings-settings-to-save-and

Answer (score 1):

Here is [an article with methods you need](http://snipplr.com/view/24482/). SaveAs is named Export and Load is Import in the article.

But I could say from my experience that if you want to use application settings in custom manner it is better to implement custom SettingsProvider. Here is a good [example of implementing custom SettingsProvider and storing configs in separated xml](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20917/Creating-a-Custom-Settings-Provider) files (which is, I believe, exactly what you need).