# saving state between program restarts

Tags: c#, .net

How can I declare a variable which would save sting forever?

I mean if the user closes and restarts the program, this string value is not lost.

How can this be done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132544/net-configuration-app-config-web-config-settings-settings

Comment: var text = Load(); Whatever it means

Comment: @ArturMustafin: And this requires 4 comments for 1 sad story?

Comment: I retag to delete wpf tag. It has no close relation to WPF.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of different ways to store state for an application. The approach really depends on the type of data you are storing and other requirements

**Options**

- Use the Settings classes built into .NET

  - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=VS.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)
- Store the data in some type of file or database
- Send the data to a webservice or the cloud

Comment: Don't forget config files! Though I would only tend to use them for deployed state.

Comment: thanks i know that. I forgot to say which is safest way so in cofig file anyone can see content

Comment: So you have information that is sensative or you don't otherwise want seen? All of the options could be stored in an encrypted form.  The remote web service or cloud option also gives you the chance to revoke access if needed.

Answer (score 3):

Save the variable value to a database or other storage.

Comment: Database is most popular and easiest to move to another program if you want. Other alternatives are config/property files or registry settings.

Comment: It's tagged `WPF`, so it's a Windows app, not a web app.

Answer (score 2):

You could save it to a file, a database, a USB drive, somewhere in the cloud... somewhere other than the computer's memory.

Here's a quick example in C# (to write to a file):

```
string someString = "I will be here forever... well kind of";

using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(@"C:\myfile.txt"))
{
   outfile.Write(someString);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a database, in particular [SQLite](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://www.sqlite.org/&ei=U7h7Tt-rLKfu0gH_lu2-Ag&usg=AFQjCNEakQjCFFXx7pu-fq8qk9wUOlC1Bg&sig2=YK6CMZ81i4ya4BPG4sH4sg).