# How to make a program restart itself

Tags: c#

Been trying to make my program restart from a button click in the program and codes like "restart()" and "recreate()" dont exist. Any idea what code would work?

Comment: I’m really sorry if I’m incorrect to ask this, but: are you serious? It’s just the combination of C# and Java tags and “trying random codes” that makes me think otherwise.

Comment: i dont get you. AT ALL!

Comment: If winforms app: `Application.Restart`

Comment: @user3577705 minitech was referring to the fact that you are treating programming as if it was magic. Don't.

Comment: @minitech I hope I don't even need to flag this one for you...

Comment: You are likely looking for something else... But your precise question - use `Process.Start` with path to executable (both parts are easily searchable on SO/MSDN).

Comment: i mean i tried restart and it aint working.

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel It doesn't even have to be a Windows Forms app.  He can import the library and use that method in a WPF app if he/she chooses to do so.

Comment: so i guess someone can tell me how to go about with the library import. and yes its a window form.

Comment: @kbluue If it's a Windows Forms app, you don't have to import anything -- you already have it.  Just see my answer.  Otherwise, simply right click `References` under `Solution Explorer` and choose `Add Reference...`.  Scroll down until you see `System.Windows.Forms` and check it.  Then click `OK`.  That's it.

Comment: @B.K thanks man. it totally worked

Comment: @B.K it goes off and comes back on. so i was thinking, for user experience, if i could store the initial state so that the restart command would just repaint. but i have a lot of items and i cant treat my checkboxs  in an array. an ideas?

Comment: @kbluue http://stackoverflow.com/a/7522298/2006048  For a lot of my applications I use settings files and SQLite databases.  To each is own and it all depends on what you do and what environment you're developing for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do something like this:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Restart();  // it does exist...
Application.Current.Shutdown(); // If you are using WPF, otherwise see below...
```

Use `Application.Exit()` or `this.Close()` for the second line in a Windows Forms App.