# Launch an application from another application, resumes always to root activity

Tags: java, android

I created a application to launch other with this code:

```
Intent i;
    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    try {
        i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example");

        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        if (i == null)
            throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();

        startActivity(i);

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) 
    {
```

This code works correctly (can start application) for Facebook, Google Maps, another application created by me (com.example).

My test aplication (com.example) can resume, but always to root activity.
This application has two activities. First activity (Main Launcher), and a second activity. When I navigate to second activity (Main -> second), and execute application Launcher (above code), my application test run to foreground, but always show the first activity and destroy the second activity.

The test application (com.example) manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Main"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" 
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true">

           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Screen2"
            android:label="@string/screen2Title"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Facebook and Google Maps resume the last visible activity (not launcher activity).
Properties are well defined in above manifest?

The behavior of Facebook and Google Maps, is standard, or results of the code of activities, etc?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: My application works correctly in all other scenarios. Only fail when it is started from another.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, with the solution below.
Now I can start my application, if it is closed or resume (resume in any activity).

The code that starts the application is (Launcher):

```
Intent i;
    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    try 
    {
        i.addFlags(0);
        i.setPackage(null);

        if (i == null)
            throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();

        startActivity(i);

    } 
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) 
    {
    }
```

My application that starts, has the following manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Main" >

           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Screen2"
            android:label="@string/screen2Title"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" 
             android:launchMode="singleTask" >
           </activity>  
        <activity android:name=".Screen3"
            android:label="@string/screen3Title"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" 
             android:launchMode="singleTask"  >

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Now the application is resumed to any activity, without ever navigate to the root activity.