# DLL save data - Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, windows-8

I am making an app using Visual studio for the windows 8 platform. I need to be able to save some data which includes two strings and an array.

I have been searching online about how to save data, many posts have said that I need to save the data in a DLL. However none of these posts cover how you can do it using C#.

Does anyone know how I can do this in C#? The has to be saved permanently, so when the app is opened up again, I can access and use that data. Or if the machine is restarted, the app can still access its old data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best practice to save application settings in a Windows Forms Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-forms-application)

Comment: What kind of app is it? Win forms? WPF? Windows Store?

Comment: possible duplicate of [saving state between program restarts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522228/saving-state-between-program-restarts)

Comment: :@MariusBancila Its a windows form app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create DLLs, you have to set up your Visual Studio

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164704.aspx