# Saving Program State and Loading Again

Tags: c#

I am making a video Converter in c# on windows Framework.
i want to save loaded files that user add & if it Exit the Application i want to store that files and load when it runs application again.
How to do this. ?? Give me idea about how to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [saving state between program restarts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522228/saving-state-between-program-restarts)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could create a Settings class which contains a list of the files previously loaded and then on Exit serialize it to disk and on start deserialize it.

Comment: Can you give a little bit demo on it any relavent link.

Comment: The Problem with the Framework is that sometimes if you update the application the Settings might be lost. But sure you can first try the built in solution

Comment: @ThomasHahn There is no problem whatsoever with the builtin application settings if you use them as designed.

Comment: Wow i didn't know that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the settings api may help:
http://geekswithblogs.net/mbcrump/archive/2010/06/17/configuring-applicationuser-settings-in-wpf-the-easy-way.aspx

Comment: Link-only answers are generally advised against. Please at least provide a summary of what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use user settings. Open the project properties in Visual Studio and click the "Settings" tab. You can add a new **user** setting there of type `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection` by entering a setting name, selecting the type `System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection` from the combo box and then defining it as a user scope setting.

*If you forget to make it a user setting and create an application setting instead, it will be read-only and you have no chance of changing it. Only user settings can be changed.*

This will look to your code like a normal list of strings. You can add a new value to the like and save it like this:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.[Setting name you chose].Add("My String");
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Of course you can also loop over the entries like:

```
foreach (string s in Properties.Settings.Default.[Setting name you chose])
    ....
```

The advantage is that you don't need to care about where the settings are stored and how. .NET does all that for you.

---

Background: Creating settings will add them to the `app.config` file. This file will be copied into the output directory when you compile as `[exename].exe.config`. When the application starts, the framework will read the application settings from there. The user settings will either be read from there or (if you changed and saved them) from a copy that resides somewhere in the user's application data directory.

Do not, I repeat: **do not** attempt to modify that `.exe.config` file directly from your code, but always use the properties that are automatically generated for you as I described above.

Comment: I generally find that the string collection is more hassle than help, i doesn't implement IEnumerable<string> which means its not compatible directly with some of the more useful Linq extensions and causes quite a bit of bloat in your settings file. I'd only recommend it when you are storing complex strings that are hard to split, otherwise just use a string

Comment: Yes, but for the OP's purpose it is perfect. He needs to store a list of files (I guess: file names?). Probably he has a list of files internally anyway, so re-loading these files is a simple for-loop. I doubt that being able to use LINQ outweighs the pain of splitting up a string that contains all the file names in this case... Also, while LINQ may be a nice tool, we were able to program without it only 5 years ago. You can still write loops, you know? But that's a different discussion :-) As for the bloated settings file: Who cares whether the file is 1K or 2K or even 10K?