# Using GenerateDefaultValueInCode on project settings

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, settings, app-config

I recently came across this question

[.NET Configuration (app.config/web.config/settings.settings)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132544/net-configuration-app-config-web-config-settings-settings)

I've been trying to get this to work.  I've set the value of GenerateDefaultValueInCode to false for each of my settings, as before the default settings could not be overriden at run time.

I was expecting the values to now be taken from the app.config file, but this isn't happening at run time.  Even though I have got the setting values I want in my app.config file, they're not being picked up at run time.  When I debug through the code, the settings that I'm getting back are null.  Any suggestions?